# Achieve wmpdmc audio casting via the Windows.Media.Casting (UWP)

Tags: windows, uwp, mp3, audio-streaming, upnp

For several versions of Windows, you've been able to right click on an MP3 file, and you'll see a menu item labeled "Cast to Device"

[image]

When I select my sonos device as listed above, it opens an app called "Cast to Device" - C:\Windows\System32\wmpdmc.exe and the media is streamed to my sonos:

[image]

I would like to build my own application that achieves this same thing. I downloaded the sample listed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/basicmediacasting/

I changed:
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BasicMediaCasting/cs/Scenario3_CustomPicker.xaml.cs#L36

to reference CastingPlaybackTypes.Audio

and left everything else the same. But when I run, the device enumeration finds no devices. Does anyone know how I can leverage an API to perform the same streaming that I've outlined here, to a device that's found via the "Cast to Device" context menu item?

If this is not possible, I'd love to know if it's possible to automate the launching of wmpdmc with command line parameters.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

> and left everything else the same. But when I run, the device enumeration finds no devices.

For the testing, all the casting devices have **paired** for current PC, we could find them in System setting devices page. So we need pair the device before casting. And please make sure your device contains audio capability when we edit the `CastingPlaybackTypes` as `Audio`.

> I'd love to know if it's possible to automate the launching of wmpdmc with command line parameters.

You could launch `Wmplayer` with command line, for more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/command-line-parameters).

Comment: Hi Nico, the referenced document doesn't show any flags for casting audio. The device _should_ support casting audio because I can hear audio when I cast through the right click menu, but I don't know how to validate beyond that. Lastly, I don't know if / how the concept of pairing applies if the device is not bluetooth (it's on my local network), but in the "bluetooth and other devices" settings page, I do see it listed.

Comment: It could works for video projection, if the video device in the same LAN and support video projection. The device flag will show in the device setting page, you could find them in the casting list.

Comment: I'm not trying to achieve anything with video projection. My use case is that I can currently cast audio to a device on my local network via the method shown above, but I would like to achieve the same thing with an API.

Comment: To ask it another way, I'm trying to understand what audio sources are available for the casting method shown above, and then trying to understand how to cast to those sources via an API.

Comment: For better understanding Media casting, you could refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-casting) document. If the audio source could be played in `MediaPlayerElement` and it could also be casting.